# THE English language or English Language?

Tags: grammar

Which is correct? 
I have been successful in teaching the English language

Comment: @Peter Shor But this question is asking about whether the initial L in the word *language* should be capitalised here.

Comment: @Araucaria: Is it? Before the edit, the title was *"THE English language or English Language."* Then somebody "helpfully" fixed the grammar and de-emphasized *THE*. I've rolled it back now.

Comment: @peterShor. Ah, I see.